# Cite appendix from guest author (APA)

Tags: citations, citation-style

I need to cite the appendix of a book that I already cited somewhere else in my paper, but the appendix was written by a guest author whose name is not among the author names of the book. Does this mean I should have two entries in my bibliography, one for the entire book and one just for the appendix? Or should I just ignore the fact that the appendix was written by someone else? I'm supposed to use APA style.